# How to resume a thread when a second thread deletes value from a map?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am creating boost threads and storing its address in a map.
These threads would continuously run and iterate over a (say) mapA until i do a thread interrupt.

Now the question:

I want to remove a value in the mapA.
I want to make this thread sleep until the deletion of the value in the mapA is done.Once the deletion is done, the thread should continue its work.

```
Thread1
{
   ...Code...
   ...Code...
   loop over mapA
   ...Code...
   ...Code...
}

Thread2
{
   sleep(Thread1)
   until
   value in the mapA is deleted
   Continue(Thread1)
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: thread 1 has to sleep until thread 2 has finished its work and deleted? sounds a bit like a semaphore for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use condition variables for that, schematically using boost:

```
boost::mutex mutex;
boost::condition_variable cond;

Thread1
{
  boost::scoped_lock lock(mutex);

  ....
  // Looping over map done
  cond.notify_one();
}

Thread2
{
  boost::scoped_lock lock(mutex);

  // wait for end of thread1
  cond.wait(lock);

  // when we get here we continue, and lock is protecting concurrency from thread1 again
  ...
}
```

This will work well even in cases you have multiple produces/consumers.

Comment: is a mutex really enough? For me it sounded like a typical semaphore.

Comment: It's enough, mutex is for exclusivity, technically it's kind of semaphore. And in real code you rarely need full heavyweight semaphore, most of the times you need just mutexes and rwlocks (which are implemented by means of mutex anyway).